# multiple mobile numbers in textarea and searialize in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am stuck at one place, I need your help. I am trying to build one sms application type here client required the textarea where he can copy paste or enter multiple mobile numbers. I want the count and only 10 digit mobile number to send the sms in controller(codeigniter) how to do that any help?

I didn't try any code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the insert structure look like, 1234567890,9876543210... ? or you are using space or enter

Comment: For textarea you can use HTML ```textarea``` form element. Where copy-paste will work. For entering multiple mobile numbers u can use comma separated mobile numbers technique. Again, to extract all mobile numbers from comma separated string u can use PHP ```explode()``` function with ```count()``` to check the length of mobile numbers to check those are 10 digit numbers or not.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your textarea you need to determine what you want your delimiter should be. A good one is a comma or you can use a new line character. Then when you submit the form you can use explode to convert your passed data into a manageable array.

textarea with content like this:

```
5165165151561,651651651,651651651,651651651,651651651651,6516515151
```

in the `PHP` processing logic:

```
<?php
$delimiter = ','
$input = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numbers');
$numbers = explode($delimiter, $input);

print_r($numbers);
//^ would output

<?php
   Array [
            0 => 5165165151561,
            1 => 651651651,
            2 => 651651651,
            3 => 651651651,
            4 => 651651651651,
            5 => 6516515151
        ];
```

Now you can loop through the numbers to validate them

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    if($i >= 10){
        echo 'Too many numbers submitted';
    }

    if (!number_validates($numbers[$i])) {// you will need to write the validation function and logic
        echo 'Number input ' . ($i + 1) . ' has failed validation';
        exit; // you would probably want to store error in a session and redirect
    }
}
...
/*Code to send SMS*/
...
echo 'All numbers validated and sms sent successfully';
```

**NOTE**

This might not be the exact code to use but it should give you an idea how to manage multiple pieces of data in a single textarea.

you could replace `,` with `"\n"`as your delimiter and have each number on a new line instead.